# List.Contains doesn't return true when element exists

Tags: c#, list

I have got a little problem.

I have a list of int arrays that contains of ID (any number) and Count (which can be anything from 0 to 5) which is named `playerWordList` and second list with IDs only with name `words`. What I'm trying to do is a function that checks if every ID from second list is present in first (Count doesn't matter) and if it is not present, add element with that missing ID and Count equal to 0.

At the moment, I have a workaround, which is double loop that for every element in second list iterates through every element in first list looking for a match, but I see that there is a method `List.Contains` that would perfectly match in my problem but it is just not working properly.

I read a few topic on SO about it, but they mainly focus on comparing two elements of custom class, which require overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but I don't know if it applies to my problem in any way, and if it does, then I have no idea how can I override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for int arrays.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var word in unit.words)
{
    int[] ex1 = new int[2] { word.id, 0 };
    int[] ex2 = new int[2] { word.id, 1 };
    int[] ex3 = new int[2] { word.id, 2 };
    int[] ex4 = new int[2] { word.id, 3 };
    int[] ex5 = new int[2] { word.id, 4 };
    int[] ex6 = new int[2] { word.id, 5 };

    if (playerWordList.Contains(ex1) ||
        playerWordList.Contains(ex2) ||
        playerWordList.Contains(ex3) ||
        playerWordList.Contains(ex4) ||
        playerWordList.Contains(ex5) ||
        playerWordList.Contains(ex6)) break;
    else
    {
        int[] newWord = new int[2] { word.id, 0 };

        playerWordList.Add(newWord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for a built-in type but you can implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.100).aspx) for `int[]` and pass it to [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.100).aspx) method.This is usually the way to go, but if you want a quick way, you can simply use `Any` method with `SequenceEqual`:

```
if(playerWordList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(ex1) ||
                           x.SequenceEqual(ex2) ||
                           x.SequenceEqual(ex3) ||
                           x.SequenceEqual(ex4) ||
                           x.SequenceEqual(ex5) ||
                           x.SequenceEqual(ex6))
```

Comment: What is that "x => x.SequenceEqual(ex1)" thingy? I see it very often, but I can't search for it since only thing in it is that arrow and it seems useful

Comment: SequenceEqual checks if two sequence have the same elements in the same order.

Comment: Okay, but I was asking about that "=>". Is it LINQ?

Comment: it is used to create a lambda expression.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Contains checks on **reference equality**. So these object instances should be the same. It **doesn't check** on **value equality**. I suspect that you insert other instances of ex1(2,3,4,5) somewhere else and that contains doesn't return true because of the references not being equal.

Hope this clarifies some things.

This will work:

```
int[] ex1 = new int[2] { word.id, 0 };
playerWordList.Insert(ex1)
if(playerWordList.Contains(ex1))
  // returns true
```

But if you create and insert ex1 somewhere else and put it in the `playerWordList` and then in your foreach create "new" instances of ex objects than these are actually different references to different objects (although with the same values, but `Contains` doesn't compare values but references ;)

Comment: So if I understood correctly, Contains method is generally useless in my case unless I override/modify it, right?